# Building a Windows 10 (UWP) with PhoneGap?

Tags: windows, cordova, uwp, phonegap

I have read that you can make a Windows 10 UWP app using PhoneGap. However, I have not been able to find any other information on this. No documentation, no examples of other apps that have been built. Nothing.

Does anyone else know if you can build UWP apps with PhoneGap? If so, where can any information or documentation be found? Also, if anyone knows of any UWP apps that have been built this way that I could check out would be helpful too.

Comment: Not sure about cordova, but you can build UWP apps using JavaScript, HTML, CSS

Comment: @lazerbrains Did my answer solve your problem? Are you able to build UWP apps now?

Comment: Yes it did Phonolog. I appreciate you help and I just up voted you and gave you credit. Thanks so much.

Comment: Awesome, I'm glad it worked :)

Comment: Glad for knowing this! Now to dev.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can!

According to the [docs](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/windows/index.html#target-windows-version) you'll have to add following line to your config.xml:

```
<preference name="windows-target-version" value="10.0" />
```

Afterwards `cordova build windows` should create UWP apps.

---

If you want to specify the target at each `build` command you can use the [`--appx` parameter](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/windows/index.html#the---appx-parameter) like so:

```
cordova build windows -- --appx=uap
```

The docs say following about possible values for the `--appx` parameter:

> Valid values for the --appx flag are 8.1-win, 8.1-phone, and uap (for
>   Windows 10 Universal Apps). These options also apply to the cordova
>   run command.